# Adding jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar causing error

Tags: tomcat, prometheus, jmx, prometheus-node-exporter, jmx-exporter

I have been able to successfully extract JMX metrics using jmx prometheus exporter when I add below as a javaagent to my standalone jar using command

```
-javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.15.0.jar=8089:config.yaml -jar myjar.jar
```

but when I add this to the tomcat server as VM options.
It gives below error and fails to extract any jmx information:

> SEVERE [prometheus-http-1-4] io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JmxCollector.collect JMX scrape failed: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory]
> at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:369)
> at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:270)
> at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JmxScraper.doScrape(JmxScraper.java:94)
> at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JmxCollector.collect(JmxCollector.java:547)
> at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.findNextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:207)
> at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.nextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:240)
> at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.nextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:161)
> at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.exporter.common.TextFormat.write004(TextFormat.java:65)
> at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.exporter.common.TextFormat.writeFormat(TextFormat.java:47)
> at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.exporter.HTTPServer$HTTPMetricHandler.handle(HTTPServer.java:72)
> at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
> at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
> at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
> at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
> at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
> at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory]
> at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:674)
> at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
> at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
> at javax.naming.InitialContext.(InitialContext.java:216)
> at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1953)
> at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1922)
> at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:287)
> ... 18 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
> at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:72)
> at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:61)
> at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:672)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jmx_exporter code:

JmxCollector.java line 138:

```
    if (yamlConfig.containsKey("hostPort")) {
          if (yamlConfig.containsKey("jmxUrl")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("At most one of hostPort and jmxUrl must be provided");
          }
          cfg.jmxUrl ="service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + (String)yamlConfig.get("hostPort") + "/jmxrmi";
   } else if (yamlConfig.containsKey("jmxUrl")) {
          cfg.jmxUrl = (String)yamlConfig.get("jmxUrl");
   }
```

JmxScraper.java line 79:

```
    if (jmxUrl.isEmpty()) {
          beanConn = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    }
```

So,I removed the jmxUrl and hostport configuration from the config.yml file. Class Not Found Exception did not occur

Answer (score 2):

Having fiddled around, I found that I need to remove jmxUrl from my config.yml.It need not any of the jmxUrl and hostport when talking to the local JVM

Comment: this is the correct answer. when running as agent you don't need to setup the jmx url or the hostPort... you don't need to change the code.